# Regular ADK board vs Uno+USB Host Shield

Tags: arduino

Can anyone explain what advantages if any, there is in using a regular ADK board (Mega ADK or similar) vs using say, a Uno+ a USB host hsield?

I'm concerned about the form factor of the former.

Comment: Keep in mind there are solutions smaller (and cheaper) than either.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, but the support for those would be reduced even further...

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of the Arduino ADK is that, being purpose-built for Android accessory development, many libraries etc. are available for it. Google also supports it as the official accessory development platform for Android, but that just means you would need to find unofficial guides to help you (see below). Other that inbuilt USB and a  slightly more advanced processor, there would be no other advantage to using it over an uno with a USB shield.

If you want help on letting started with the ADK on an uno, this tutorial is pretty good: http://www.jayway.com/?p=9419/

Comment: Advantage, cost.

Comment: And USB is sufficiently complicated that you want all the pre-tested, well-supported code you can get.

Comment: @gwideman Too true.